# Python not collecting data from postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm issuing a select statement to gather data from my postgres db with python like so:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
            database=ps_db, user=ps_username, password=ps_password, host='hostname', port= '5432')

cursor = connection.cursor()

sql = ("""SELECT alert_status FROM public.alerts WHERE datetime_dbinsert >= NOW() - INTERVAL '13 seconds' and object = 'QMGR' AND object_parm = '98' ORDER BY datetime_dbinsert DESC LIMIT 1;""")

cursor.execute(sql)

record = cursor.fetchall()

print(record)
```

When I print record I get an empty return value: [ ]

However, when I take that exact sql statement and run it through dbeaver at the same exact time, I get exactly what i'm looking for:

```
CAUTION 1/3
```

I'm not really sure what's different between me doing it manually through dbeaver and doing it through python.

Oddly enough, when I do the sql without the interval it works fine so its not a connection name issue:

```
sql = ("""SELECT alert_status FROM public.alerts WHERE object = 'QMGR' AND object_parm = '98' ORDER BY datetime_dbinsert DESC LIMIT 1;""")
```

Comment: `WHERE datetime_dbinsert >= NOW() - INTERVAL '13 seconds'` presumably you are not instantaneously running the query in both your script and DBeaver, so how do you know that such queries _should_ be repeatable in that time window?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified what I did my troubleshooting. One of the things I tested was running both at the same time. The script inserts in to the table and then another part looks for previous entries before entering it again.

While that was running, I was able to successfully get a return only through DBeaver.

Comment: Why would it be "a connection name issue" (I don't follow this logic at all) and why is removing the interval "odd" when they give the same results? It's just a matter of timing, surely

Comment: The project is very large, so there is a lot of moving parts. I suppose I talk to much :)
The only thing that I need help with is why running the script and the sql via dbeaver gives me different results even when theyre run at the same time.

Comment: `now()` is alias for `transaction_timestamp()` per [Current Date/Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), which as the name implies captures the time at the start of the transaction. It is very doubtful you are starting the transactions at the same time in both cases. To verify crank up the logging and look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database. I'm betting `NOW() - INTERVAL '13 seconds'` is significantly different.